# Java8 streams to find multiple values and return boolean

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am using java-8 to find the values in list of custom object. For ex)

```
List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
        new Employee("Sachin Tendulkar", 41),
        new Employee("Sachin Tendulkar", 36),
        new Employee("MS Dhoni", 34),
        new Employee("Rahul Dravid", 40),
        new Employee("Lokesh Rahul", 25),
        new Employee("Sourav Ganguly", 40)
);
```

To find a value in a list i can use the below query,

```
boolean isPresent = employees.stream()
            .allMatch(employee -> (equalsIgnoreCase(employee.getName(),"Sachin Tendulkar") && equalsIgnoreCase(employee.getAge(),"36")));
```

The above is working fine. But I would like to find "Sachin Tendulkar" with Age 36 and "Rahul Dravid" with 40. How to achieve this in Java8 streams. I have tried multiple "allMatch" but that doesn't work.

Any hint would be appreciable.

Comment: you want to get the employee or check just if it is exist or not?

Comment: Do you want to check if your list contains both?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `anyMatch` like so :

```
boolean isPresent = employees.stream()
        .anyMatch(employee ->
                (employee.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Sachin Tendulkar") && employee.getAge() == 36)
                        ||
                        (employee.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Rahul Dravid") && employee.getAge() == 40)
        );
```

---

To get the Employee list you can use :

```
List<Employee> result = employees.stream()
        .filter(employee ->
                (employee.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Sachin Tendulkar") && employee.getAge() == 36)
                        ||
                        (employee.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Rahul Dravid") && employee.getAge() == 40)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Or you can create a List of Employee that you want to find and just use `List::containsAll`, note you have to override `hashCode` and `equals` method in your Employee class :

```
List<Employee> listToFind = Arrays.asList(
        new Employee("Sachin Tendulkar", 36),
        new Employee("Rahul Dravid", 40)
);

boolean isPresent = employees.containsAll(listToFind);
```

Comment: I have override hashcode and equals but still the "containsAll" doesn't works for me

Comment: @VelNaga how you override it and what you do exactly check this [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/5yG3Oh) for more details :)

Comment: I have used intellij equals and hashcode template to override the beans

Comment: @VelNaga I use the same IDE did you tried my code in the ideone link?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more readable solution,

```
Predicate<Employee> p1 = e -> e.getName().equals("Sachin Tendulkar") && e.getAge() == 36;
Predicate<Employee> p2 = e -> e.getName().equals("Rahul Dravid") && e.getAge() == 40;
final boolean isFound = employees.stream().filter(p1.or(p2)).findAny().isPresent();
```

A more condensed solution would be,

```
final boolean isFound = employees.stream().anyMatch(p1.or(p2));
```